# determing which tab has been opened and closed jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

have been struggling a bit with this.

How can I determine whether my jquery accordion tab is opened or closed?

```
<div id="accordion3" class="accordion">
<!-- D1 -->
    <h3 class='ach plus' id="1">Assignment Initiation Form</h3>
    <div style="width:100%;">
       content
    </div>

    <!-- D2 -->
    <h3 class='ach plus' id="2">Flag potential candidates</h3>
    <div style="width:100%;">
     content
    </div>
</div>
```

was thinking along the lines of

```
$(document).on("opened", #accordion3, function(){
     var id = $(this).find("id");
     $(id).removeClass("plus").addClass("minus");
});
```

I want to swop a class from 'plus' to 'minus' on opening of accordion and vice versa.

help appreciated

Comment: see the available events with jquery accordion,http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
       //write your code here
       ui.newHeader.removeClass('minus').addClass('plus');
       $('.ach').not('.plus').addClass('minus');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you know more http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

To get active tab index you can try below code:

```
var active = $( ".accordion" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
```

Also remember index starts with 0